# Get timezone from date string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm working on a function that should check if a given dateString has the same timeZone as the browser timeZone. To get the browser timeZone I can use either a) `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` which will return `Europe/Amsterdam` for example or b) `new Date().getTimeZoneOffset()` that will return `-60`. Both are fine.

The tricky part is to get the timeZone from the dateString I want to pass, for example from: `2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00` (which should be `America/New_York` or `300` AFAIK). How can I get the timeZone from that date? I tried to do: `new Date('2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00').getTimeZoneOffset()` but that will convert it to the timeZone of my browser again, returning `-60`.

Example of function:

```js
function isSameTimeZone(date) {
  // function to get time zone here


  const a = getTimeZone(date)
  return a === new Date().getTimeZoneOffset() || Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
}
```

**Testcases**

`2021-01-01T00:00:00-08:00` (SF)

`2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00` (NY)

`2021-01-01T00:00:00+05:30` (Mumbai)

`2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00` (Amsterdam)

Anyone out there with a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "America/New_York" is not really a timezone, it's a representative location that represents all the historic and daylight saving timezone offsets for New York, USA. There are many other places that use -5 as their standard offset that use different historic offsets (e.g. Cancun, Panama, Montreal and so on), so you can't say "-5 **is** New York", it could be any place that uses or used -5 at any time in the past or present, including for daylight saving.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method;

```js
function checkTimezone(dateString) {
  const testDate = new Date(dateString);
  const dateRegex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;
  const myDate = new Date(testDate.toISOString().match(dateRegex)[0]);
  
  return !(testDate - myDate);
}

const testCases = ['2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00', '2021-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', '2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00', '2021-01-01T00:00:00+05:30', '2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00'];
testCases.forEach(testCase => console.log(checkTimezone(testCase)));
```

So here's how it works, you pass in your date string and create a `new Date()` instance with it.

Then I get the ISO string with the `Date.ISOString()` method and match it with the original string to get the date and create another `Date` instance from it without the time.

Then I find the difference (comes in milliseconds), and convert it to minutes

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to be the solution I was looking for. I prefer to have a function that returns a bool, if the timezone of new Date() is the same as the timezone of the date passed. So it shouldn't return the difference in minutes between dates but rather compare the offset of each date. Also, have you taken into account that a timezone can either be + or -?

Comment: Let me do that then... Could you please provide more test cases

Comment: Added them in my question :)

Comment: You can check it out now

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to be working :/ Passing `2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00` to the function while my timezone is Europe/Amsterdam `Mon Mar 15 2021 22:06:39 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` will still return false. Also the array you've used is returning 5 times false even tho one of them is the same as my timezone.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been testing around a bit and in the end I came up with the following solution, based on the dates I provided in my question.

```js
  const getTimeZoneOffsetFromDate = date => {
    /*
      Check if the offset is positive or negative
      e.g. +01:00 (Amsterdam) or -05:00 (New York)
    */
    if (date.includes('+')) {
      // Get the timezone hours
      const timezone = date.split('+')[1]
      // Get the hours
      const hours = timezone.split(':')[0]
      // Get the minutes (e.g. Mumbai has +05:30)
      const minutes = timezone.split(':')[1]

      /*
        Amsterdam:
        const offset = 01 * -60 = -60 + -0 = -60
      */
      const offset = hours * -60 + parseInt(-minutes)

      return offset === new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    }

    // Repeat
    const timezone = date.slice(date.length - 5)
    const hours = timezone.split(':')[0]
    const minutes = timezone.split(':')[1]

    /*
      New York:
      const offset = 05 * 60 = 300 + 0 = 300
    */
    const offset = hours * 60 + parseInt(minutes)

    return offset === new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  }

  console.log(getTimeZoneOffsetFromDate('2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00'))
```

Comment: The [list of representative locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for timezone offsets is long, and many share the same offset but have different daylight saving offset schedules (or not at all), and different historic offsets. How do you know which one a particular offset, such as +1 or -5, applies to? E.g. Montreal and Jamaica are -5 for standard time, Canada/Central is -5 while observing DST.